# Bug in creating inverse rotation matrix

Tags: c#, matrix, rotation, algebra

I need to triangulate a 3D polygon (a planar set of ordered vertices). To do this, I rotate the polygon into the X/Z plane and apply an ear clipping algorithm to the rotated vertices. After that, I rotate the vertices back and have a triangulated polygon.
However, I seem to have an error in my rotation.
To rotate my polygons into the X/Z plane, I do the following:

First, I take the normal vector of the polygon and create an inverse rotation matrix out of it

```
    internal static Matrix4 CreateInverseRotationMatrix(Vector3 up) // up is normal vector of polygon
    {
        Vector3 right;
        // take the longer axis and calculate a normal vector
        if (up.X.AbsoluteValue > up.Z.AbsoluteValue)
            right = up.Cross(new Vector3(0, 0, 1));
        else
            right = up.Cross(new Vector3(1, 0, 0));

        // create the third vector of the matrix
        var backward = right.Cross(up);
        // create inverse rotation matrix
        Matrix4<Rational> m = new Matrix4<Rational>(right.X, right.Y, right.Z, 0, up.X, up.Y, up.Z, 0, backward.X, backward.Y, backward.Z, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
        return m;
    }
```

After that, I multiply each vertex with the inverse rotation matrix:

```
    private List<Vector2> CreateRotatedVertexList(List<Vertex3> contourVertices, Vector3 up)
    {
        var matrix = Matrix4.CreateInverseRotationMatrix(up);
        List<Vector2> points = new List<Vector2>();
        foreach (var vertex in contourVertices)
        {
            var rotatedVertex = Matrix4.Multiply(matrix, vertex.Vector3);
            var point = new Vector2m(rotatedVertex.X, rotatedVertex.Z);
            points.Add(point);
        }

        return points;
    }
```

The Matrix4.Multiply looks like this:

```
    public static Vector3 Multiply(Matrix4 m, Vector3 vec4)
    {
        Vector3 res = Vector3.Zero();
        res.X = m.M11 * vec4.X + m.M12 * vec4.Y + m.M13 * vec4.Z + m.M14;
        res.Y = m.M21 * vec4.X + m.M22 * vec4.Y + m.M23 * vec4.Z + m.M24;
        res.Z = m.M31 * vec4.X + m.M32 * vec4.Y + m.M33 * vec4.Z + m.M34;
        var w = m.M41*vec4.X + m.M42*vec4.Y + m.M43*vec4.Z + m.M44;
        return res;
    }
```

I have drawn an example polygon in Blender. For example, the polygon P ={(-1 1 1), (-0.5 1 0.5), (0 1 0), (0.5 0.5 0), (1 0 0), (1 -0.5 0.5), (1 -1 1)}

[image]

And the rotated polygon PR = {(0 1 -4) (0,5 1 -2,5) (1 1 -1) (0,5 1 0,5) (0 1 2) (-1 1 2) (-2 1 2)}.

[image]

The y-components of the rotated vertices are all 1, so the polygon lies in the X/Z plane, thats correct. But the shape of the rotated polygon looks clearly different, compared to the unrotated polygon and I don't know why.

Comment: Are you using Point or FPoint?  Use FPoint which is floating point arithmetic.  Point will round number to integers which may account for the change in shape.

Comment: The internal datatype of all classes is double

Comment: Try : new Vector3m(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)

Comment: Sorry, the "m" in Vector3 is a typo, I fixed it. You mean instead of the if/else branch, just writing "right = up.Cross(new Vector3(0, 0, 1));" ? I have tried this and it really worked! Maybe you could explain me why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have forgotten to normalize the basis vectors. So it should be:

```
internal static Matrix4 CreateInverseRotationMatrix(Vector3 up) // up is normal vector of polygon
{
    Vector3 right;
    up = up.Unit();
    // take the longer axis and calculate a normal vector
    if (up.X.AbsoluteValue > up.Z.AbsoluteValue)
        right = up.Cross(new Vector3(0, 0, 1));
    else
        right = up.Cross(new Vector3(1, 0, 0));
    right = right.Unit();
    // create the third vector of the matrix
    var backward = right.Cross(up);
    // create inverse rotation matrix
    Matrix4<Rational> m = new Matrix4<Rational>(right.X, right.Y, right.Z, 0, up.X, up.Y, up.Z, 0, backward.X, backward.Y, backward.Z, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    return m;
}
```